# Локальные переменные и списки

Tags: python

```
def fucn1(nums1: list[int], nums2: list[int]) -> list[list[int]]:
        answer = [nums1, nums2]

def func2(a, b):
        ans = [a, b]
```

Объясните пожалуйста, почему если изменить значение `answer[0]`, меняется значение `nums1`, но при изменении `ans[0]` значение `а` не поменяется?

Comment: А что такое a и b? Пример должен быть воспроизводим

Comment: списки передаются по ссылке, а значения `a` копируется

Comment: если a - список, то тоже по ссылке, и содержимое a изменится. Поэтому и нужно приводить конкретный пример

Comment: "если изменить значение answer[0]" - а как именно вы это делаете? Если answer[0] = чего_то, то nums1 при этом не изменится.

Comment: @CrazyElf в этом и дело, что меняется

Comment: @SulekLevrone Если делаете `+=` или `.append`, то поменяется, да. Потому что это ссылка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Допустим, есть у нас список:

```
a=['foo', 'bar']
```

Если вы просто напишите `b=a`, то `b` будет *зависеть* от `a` (*иначе говоря, `b` станет ссылкой на `a`*), то есть когда мы изменяем элемент в списке `а`, то этот же элемент изменится в списке `b`. И наоборот. Пример:

```
a=['foo', 'bar']
b=a
b[0]='python'
print(b) #['python', 'bar']
print(a) #['python', 'bar']
a[0]=1
print(a) #[1, 'bar']
print(b) #[1, 'bar']
```

Это работает только со списками (массивами). Чтобы создать *независимую копию* списка, используйте стандартный метод `.copy()`. Например:

```
a=['foo', 'bar']
b=a.copy()
b[0]='python'
print(b) #['python', 'bar']
print(a) #['foo', 'bar']
a[0]=1
print(a) #[1, 'bar']
print(b) #['python', 'bar']
```

---

P.S. Я разобрал это при условии, что `a` и `b` у *автора вопроса* в коде **не** являются списками